# Wireshark filter per ip address "different from" something

Tags: wireshark

I'd like to get all captured packets in which the origin or the destination ip address is different from, say, 192.168.0.1. For that purpose I tried ip.addr != 192.168.0.1, but the filter turns yellow, instead of green, so something must be wrong.

How can that be (correctly) done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 6.4.4. A common mistake
>
> [Warning] Warning! Using the != operator on combined expressions like:
>   eth.addr, ip.addr, tcp.port, udp.port and alike will probably not work
>   as expected!
>
> Often people use a filter string to display something like ip.addr ==
>   1.2.3.4 which will display all packets containing the IP address 1.2.3.4.
>
> Then they use ip.addr != 1.2.3.4 to see all packets not containing the
>   IP address 1.2.3.4 in it. Unfortunately, this does not do the
>   expected.
>
> Instead, that expression will even be true for packets where either
>   source or destination IP address equals 1.2.3.4. The reason for this,
>   is that the expression ip.addr != 1.2.3.4 must be read as "the packet
>   contains a field named ip.addr with a value different from 1.2.3.4".
>   As an IP datagram contains both a source and a destination address,
>   the expression will evaluate to true whenever at least one of the two
>   addresses differs from 1.2.3.4.
>
> If you want to filter out all packets containing IP datagrams to or
>   from IP address 1.2.3.4, then the correct filter is !(ip.addr ==
>   1.2.3.4) as it reads "show me all the packets for which it is not true that a field named ip.addr exists with a value of 1.2.3.4", or in
>   other words, "filter out all packets for which there are no
>   occurrences of a field named ip.addr with the value 1.2.3.4".

[Source](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChWorkBuildDisplayFilterSection.html#ChWorkBuildDisplayFilterMistake)